# Как выровнять блок-контейнер по центру страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container" >
        Контейнер
    </div>
</body>
```

Как выровнять блок `.container` по центру `<body>` независимо от ширины страницы?

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: @HamSter, я так тоже в начале ответил, но в вопросе написано: **по центру страницы**. То есть не только по **осиX**, а и по **осиY**.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный,  "независимо от ширины страницы" обычно это означает по горизонтали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) или [Flex Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), но прежде убедитесь, что требование заказчика позволяет использовать эти технологии. Для этого есть хороший сайт: [Can I use...](https://caniuse.com/). Удачи!

[Вот песочница](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) для Flex;

**UPD**: Исправил пример. Подумал что нужно просто центрировать элемент по  **оси: X**. Если все же нужно просто центрировать элемент: `container` по **оси: X**, то задайте свойства: `margin: 0 auto;`, и пропишите свою ширину, ибо это блочный элемент, и он по ширине занимает всё допустимое пространство.

```css
.page {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  background: #000;
  width: 30%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body class="page">
  <div class="container">Lorem</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.container{
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `flex` в `css`

`align-items: center` по вертикали

`justify-content: center` по горизонтали

```css
.body {
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body class='body'>
    <div class="container" >
        Контейнер
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`margin: 0 auto;` - автоматические внешние отступы по горизонтали.

```css
body {margin: 0; background: #ddd;}

.container {display: block; width: 70%; height: 100vh; margin: 0 auto; background: #aaa;}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    Контейнер
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вверху, все решения грамоздкие, мое решение самое краткое и в чем-то красивое!

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body class='body'>
  <div class="container">
    Контейнер
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]